# How to store the results of Batch Command where?

Tags: python, batch-file, command

Running

```
WHERE python
```

in my bat scripts gives me two file paths to two different python instances

```
C:~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
C:~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

How would I store the first one in a variable. I am currently attempting to

```
FOR /f %%p in ('where python') do SET PYTHONPATH=%%p
```

but, it only gives me the second file path.

How would I get the first path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```sh
@For %%G In (python.exe) Do @Set "PYTHONPATH=%%~$PATH:G"
```

`where.exe` will search every location under `%PATH%`, and output all results, which is not what you want, hence the reason I've not advocated its use in this particular case.

The `%~PATH:` modifier however, will output the first result it finds.

*This is also a good reason to always make sure that your %PATH%, string values are listed in order of priority, and not just blindly prepend new locations instead of append them.*

---

To fully answer your specific question, if you wanted to still use `where.exe`, you'd just need a method of…

- Stopping the iteration after the first result:

```sh
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe python.exe 2^>NUL') Do @Set "PYTHONPATH=%%~G" & GoTo Next
:Next
```

- Defining the variable only if it isn't already defined:

```sh
@Set "PYTHONPATH="
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe python.exe 2^>NUL') Do @If Not Defined PYTHONPATH Set "PYTHONPATH=%%~G"
```